# Error with Hawkular agent in WildFly-8.2

Tags: wildfly, hawkular

We got following error with Hawkular agent in WildFly-8.2 (domain mode) running on Java 7.

> [Host Controller] Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/hawkular/agent/monitor/extension/SubsystemExtension : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Is there any option to resolve this?

Comment: This is typical of java version mismatch, and unfortunately you'll not be able to run the agent on java 7. The hawkular agent itself uses java 8.

Comment: Started wildfly-8.2 in domain mode with Java 8. The error reported in ticket gone but the metrics from this server is not showing in Grafana. Is agent supported in wildfly-8.2? As per documentation it is in standalone mode, do we need any chnages for domain?

Comment: AFAIK is not tested on wildfly 8.2, but the agent runs on a jboss-as-7. So i suppose it *might* work. Did you installed it on the host.xml file? see https://github.com/hawkular/hawkular-agent/blob/master/docker-dist/Dockerfile-wf-agent-domain#L37